# What are some good (and fast) alternatives to dynamic time warping?

Tags: time-series, clustering

I am planning to cluster tens of thousands of time series of different lengths into two groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various approximations such as Wavelets and SAX that can be used to get a lower bound.

- [Wavelets on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet)
- Piecewise Aggregate Approximation (PAA)
- [Symbolic Aggregate approXimation (SAX) homepage](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.htm)

But *first* make sure that DTW is what you *need*. It would be a big waste of time if you spent a lot of effort to scale something to a large data set which does not work... so **always start with a sample**.

For many time series, DTW is *not* usable. Instead, you may need something like fourier transformation, or **extract features from the time series**.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it a little?

Comment: "extract features from the time series" - it is means I must combine several approaches in my observation ? or how ?

Comment: Features = some interesting properties of your time series, *instead of using the raw data*. For example don't use raw audio, but extract e.g. timbre and energy instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.

Lets say you data is richly sampled. If you downsample it by 1 in 2, the speedup will be a factor of 4. 
If you downsample it by 1 in 10, the speedup will be a factor of 100.
So if your data is oversampled, this is the easiest way to get a speed up.

You can also use admissible lower bounding to speed things up [a]

[a] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Speeded%20Clustering%20Paper%20Camera%20Ready.pdf